# raytracing plane intersection only draws partial plane C++

Tags: c++, raytracing

This is a simple c++ raytracing program which gets the points where rays from a camera collide with a simple plane with no offset and the normal (1, 0, 0), and depending on the intersection of the point draws a checkerboard pattern to give a sense of space. However the plane does not draw as expected as it sometimes is cut off and/or warped. What is causing these behaviors? And why is this raytracing code wrong? Or is more information needed to answer this question?

With viewPort.x = -150, viewPort.y = 0, viewPort.z = 0, viewPort.px = 0, viewPort.py = 1, viewPort.width = 480 and viewPort.height = 360 it displays:
[Image of render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOP2X.png)

```
//viewPort is the camera, bMap is a bitmap and green is the color green
//Get sin and cos of camera angles
float sx, sy, cx, cy;
sx = sin(viewPort.px);
sy = sin(viewPort.py);
cx = cos(viewPort.px);
cy = cos(viewPort.py);

//Get angle of camera view in radians for height and width with 3:4 ratio
float fh, fw;
fh = 60 / 180 * 3.14159;
fw = fh * (1 + 1 / 3);

//Get all rays and their angles
for (int h = 0;h < viewPort.width;++h)
{
  //Get Positon of starting ray
  Point3D tmp;
  tmp.x = viewPort.x + h * cy;
  tmp.y = viewPort.y + h * sx * sy;
  tmp.z = viewPort.z + h * (0 - sy * cx);

  //Get y angle of ray
  float sh, ch, dh;
  dh = viewPort.py - ((float)(h - viewPort.width / 2) / viewPort.width / 2) * fw;
  sh = sin(dh);
  ch = cos(dh);

  for (int v = 0;v < viewPort.height;++v)
  {
    //Get x angle of ray
    float sv, cv, dv;
    dv = viewPort.px - ((float)(v - viewPort.height / 2) / viewPort.height / 2) * fh;
    sv = sin(dv);
    cv = cos(dv);

    //Get slope of ray
    float dx, dy, dz;
    dx = sv;
    dy = 0 - sh * cv;
    dz = ch * cv;

    if (dx != 0)
    {
      //Get point of intersection from normal, ray start, and ray angle
      Point3D nor = {1, 0, 0};
      Point3D lin = {dx, dy, dz};

      float denom = DotProduct(nor, lin);
      if (std::abs(denom) > 1e-6)
      {
        float mag = sqrt(tmp.x * tmp.x + tmp.y * tmp.y + tmp.z * tmp.z);

        //Point (0, 0, 0) is on plane. p0 - tmp
        Point3D p0l0 = {-tmp.x / mag, -tmp.y / mag, -tmp.z / mag};

        float t = DotProduct(p0l0, nor) / denom;

        //Check if ray is coliding (not line)
        if (t >= 0)
        {
          //Determine square of checkerboard pattern
          if ((int)((t * dy + tmp.y) / 16) % 2 == 0)
          {
            if ((int)std::abs((t * dz + tmp.z) / 16) % 2 == 0)
            {
              bMap.SetPixel(h, v, green);
            }
          }
          else
          {
            if ((int)std::abs((t * dz + tmp.z) / 16) % 2 == 1)
            {
              bMap.SetPixel(h, v, blue);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    //Offset ray position by one
    tmp.y += cx;
    tmp.z += sx;
  }
}
```

Comment: What does it draw? Suggest including a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by how the program determined the position and direction of the rays. Due to a missunderstanding of how raytracing works I was giving each ray a unique position. Instead all rays should share the same position and be mapped to screen space based on the angle of the ray scaled by the screen position and centered in each pixel. Which should account for each quadrant in screen space. Thus:

angle_x = (2 * ((screen_x + 0.5) / screen_width) - 1) * tan(pi / 2 * fov / 180) * ascpect_ratio

angle_y = (1 - 2 * ((screen_y + 0.5) / screen_height)) * tan(pi / 2 * fov / 180)